# Tailwind CSS - NavBar does not overlap the content

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I tried by making it relative, also tried by changing z index but still it is not working, I am new to tailwind, I want NavBar should stick and remain at the top and content should go behind the NavBar.

```
    function App() {
    
      const navbarData = [
        {
          text: "Home",
          link: "",
        },
        {
          text: "Internships",
          link: "/Internships",
        },
        {
          text: "Events and Activities",
          link: "/Events and Activities",
        },
        {
          text: "Contact Us",
          link: "/Contact Us",
        },
      ]
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="font-Montserrat">
            <NavBar navbarData={navbarData} />
            <div className=" w-full h-[2000px] bg-red-700"></div>
            {/* <Heading text={"About Us"}/>
            <Footer/> */}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;



const NavBar = ({navbarData}) => {
  return (
    <header className='w-screen sticky z-30 top-0 px-7 h-20 flex items-center justify-around shadow-md'>
      <div className="w-[80%] flex justify-between content-center">
      <div className='flex items-center justify-center pt-1'>
        {
          // logos.map((logo,index)=>(
          //   <img src={logo.src} key={index} alt={logo.alt} className='h-12 mx-3' />
          // ))
        }
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-row px-16 items-center'>
        <nav >
          <ul className='flex gap-12 pb-2 '>
            {
              navbarData.map((item,index)=>(
                <li key={index} className='cursor-pointer font-semibold text-oirBrown hover:text-oirOrange'>{item.text}</li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
          <hr className=' border-oirOrange w-[110%]' />
        </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex'>
       <Button text={"Login/SignUp"}/>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

[watch this video to view problem][1]
[1]: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/85486891/221359841-8d2c9551-5f53-4478-9346-e115bf940125.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a background-color property to the header element.

You can do that with class `bg-{color}`.

Read more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color).

```js
<header className='bg-white w-screen sticky z-30 top-0 px-7 h-20 flex items-center justify-around shadow-md'>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried position fixed?

```
position: fixed;
top:0;
```